# How to get order list of customer using graphql?

Tags: customer, magento2.3, graphql

How to get order list of customer using graphql.

I have below code to get order list using graphql but can't get it.

schema.graphqls

```
type Query {
    salesOrder (
        customer_id: Int @doc(description: "Id of the Sales Order")
    ): SalesOrder @resolver(class: "<vendor>\\<Module>\\Model\\Resolver\\CustomerOrder") @doc(description: "The Sales Order query returns information about a Sales order")
}

type SalesOrder @doc(description: "Sales Order graphql gather Data of specific order information") {
    order_array: [String] @doc(description: "Array of order list.")
}
```

CustomerOrder.php

```
<?php
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
/**
 * Description of CustomerOrder
 *
 * @author dharmendra
 */
class CustomerOrder implements ResolverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        $salesData = $this->getSalesData($args['customer_id']); 
        return $salesData;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $orderId
     * @return array
     * @throws GraphQlNoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getSalesData(int $customerId): array
    {
        try {
            $orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();
            $orders->addFieldToSelect('*');
            $orders->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId);
            $orders->setOrder('created_at','desc');

            $orderCollection = [];
            foreach($orders as $order) {
                $orderCollection[] = [
                    'increment_id' => $order->getIncrementId(),
                    'grand_total' => $order->getGrandTotal(),
                    'customer_id' => $order->getCustomerId(),
                ];
            }
            $orderData['order_array'] = $orderCollection;
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(__($e->getMessage()), $e);
        }
        return $orderData;
    }
}
```

I have getting single order details perfect using graphql. But I want to get list of all order placed by customer using graphql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Check What is GraphQL in Magento 2, Read Blog, [GraphQl in Magento 2](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/graphql-in-magento-2/)

Check the link, [Get List of Orders of Customer using GraphQl Magento 2 full module](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-get-list-of-customers-order-using-graphql-magento-2/)

For Get List of orders of Customer by customer id, You need to create a schema file for getting a response from Query.

In above you have declared schema file for getting multiple records of order for a specific customer.

```
type SalesOrder @doc(description: "Sales Order graphql gather Data of specific order information") {
    order_array: [String] @doc(description: "Array of order list.") }
```

In above **order_array** is used for getting an array of records but in your resolver, you made mistakes for multiple records.

In **$orderCollection[]** you need to pass array key for each record and you forgot to add that in your code.

You can try with,

```
foreach($orders as $k => $order) {
            $orderCollection['order_array'][$k] = [
                'increment_id' => $order->getIncrementId(),
                'grand_total' => $order->getGrandTotal(),
                'customer_id' => $order->getCustomerId(),
            ];
        }
```

Let me know if you have any query.