# How to get customer group id into magento2 graphql

Tags: magento2, graphql

How to get customer group id into graphql magento2

**Note: Only in GraphQL**

Comment: Follow this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248558/how-to-get-order-list-of-customer-using-graphql may be helpful to you

Comment: @PradipGarchar, Thank you for comment. but i want to get customer group id which  passing customer id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much clear what you are looking for. If you want to get the customer group_id in customer graphql query you can directly provide the output variable as below.

```
{
  customer {
    firstname
    lastname
    suffix
    email
    group_id
  }
}
```

Comment: How to get customer id ?

Answer (score 0):

Note: This only you'll get if customer is logged in in your Model Resolver file:

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function getGroupId(){
if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
    $customerGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
endif;
}
```

After this you can set $customerGroupId variable as a array of your module.